# How can we restart the chain if it becomes stuck during data migration?

Tags: validator, migration, block-production, solo-chain

I performed a runtime upgrade on the chain, but due to a migration failure, the chain stopped producing blocks. The logs only show that the migration failed.

When I attempt to restart the validators, they do not start producing blocks. Instead, they continue to display block data with the migration error.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should label that block as a bad block in the chain spec file, you can check Kusama's chain spec file for an example.
Clear the validators' database and resynchronize to the previous block.
This is a "hard fork" I think.

Comment: i am trying that but chain starting from same state. Maybe some issue in bad block implementation. 
Any steps or doc to apply bad block to the chain?

Comment: Getting this error after following this 
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/how-to-solve-detected-prevote-equivocation-in-the-finality-worker-issue