# How can we start the solo chain with existing chain data?

Tags: solo-chain, fork

I got this issue in my prod chain
[How can we restart the chain if it becomes stuck during data migration?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/how-can-we-restart-the-chain-if-it-becomes-stuck-during-data-migration)

I am not able to start the chain. Is there any way to start the chain with existing database.

Comment: you can add `--base-path /path/to/database` flag when starting the chain. if you are doing `--dev` I think your database will be in the /tmp which will be deleted every new start.

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that first we need to export the state of the chain on any given blocknumber.

```
./target/release/chain-node export-state --chain=currentChainSpecRaw.json --base-path /Users/pcs/documents/node01 1000 > chain-exported-100.json
```

Then you need to start the the chain with the exported chainspec.